# The Torah Transmission Date Discrepancies?

Tags: history, tanach, mishna, talmud-bavli, tzaddikim

I'm curious to know the dates of birth and death of the following Torah transmitters, who appear in Pirkei Avot, since I've seen **conflicting dates** when doing some independent research:

Shimon HaTzadik

Antigonus of Socho

Yosei ben Yo'ezer of Tzredah

Yosei ben Yochanan of Yerushalayim

Yehoshua ben Perachiah

Nittai the Arbeli

Yehuda ben Tabbai

Shimon ben Shatach

Shemayah

Avtalyon

Hillel

Shammai

Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai

---

*I would also appreciate if you could provide the source(s) from where you salvaged the years of their births and deaths.*

Edit: Here are some of the websites where I found the dates:

1. http://rabbi.bendory.com/docs/shalshelet.php
2. http://www.yashanet.com/studies/judaism101/sidebars/transmission.htm
3. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3127369/jewish/A-Timeline-of-the-Transmission-of-Torah.htm
4. http://rabbiwolbe.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Chain-of-Torah-Transmission-From-Moses-to-You-RYW.pdf
5. https://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/mesora/

Comment: Yosef, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! It would be helpful to include a list of the sources you've already consulted in the question, so that answers don't end up duplicating your effort.

Comment: I don't know about the dates of their birth and death, but the sefer Seder HaDoros HaKotzar clearly details these personalities and where they lie in history. You can access it here - https://tablet.otzar.org/en/pages/?&restore=1&t=1611250816373

Comment: Unfortunately, even much more recent historical figures have doubts as to their precise years of birth and death. I can't imagine it gets better the farther back you go.

Comment: @N.T. I understand, however my point is that discrepancies in the transmission dates could lead to gaps in the chain of Torah transmission, which is problematic...

Comment: If I had to guess you're probably you're seeing estimates that take different positions about the famous 167 Missing Years from the Persian era

Comment: @Yosef For most of them, the only source for dates is the fact that they taught or learned under someone whose date is actually known. So the Torah transmission gives the dates, not vica versa.

Comment: @N.T. If that is so, why are there conflicting dates?

Comment: There could be a conflicting date for one person whose time is described relative to a historical event, e.g. R' Akiva and the Churban. That will then have a domino effect on his students and on.

Comment: @Dov Could u kindly quote (preferably a copy and paste) where in Seder HaDoros HaKotzar it is written about the abovementioned personalities? Much appreciated, since I can't seem to find the book on the website u linked.

Comment: @Yosef the whole book is currently accessible on the Otzar site. If you look through the index page starting here - https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=628137&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=406 you can find on what pages they appear. Hatzlocho!

Comment: @Dov Thank You!